# WebApi2 + CORS + OWIN fails IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have my application working well running on VS 2013, but when I publish on IIS 8.5 CORS stops working due:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried this in the web.config, but still the same:

```
 <httpprotocol>
  <customheaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"></add>
  </customheaders>
</httpprotocol>
```

The error occurs when I try to authenticate:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<myurl>/token
```

I have this configuration for OWIN, and again, Its works well running locally:

```
app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
```

Comment: Did you clear all http handlers? Some asp.net handler is probably intercepting the request before it gets to your application. Your web config should look like this <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear />
      <add name="Owin" verb="*" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" /></handlers></system.webServer>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue. I was getting a 500 error that Chrome does't intercept. After use Feddler I was able to see what really was going on with my request, and I did intecept the right Response Error.

**Important:** If you get any error at the server with CORS It will respond you as `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, I don't know why, but makes stuff difficult to trace.